# Character Eaten by Monster from a Trap Door on the Floor

Tags: identify-this-movie

The movie is in color and probably from the 1960s. I don't think it is *Mysterious Island* or *Captain Nemo and the Underwater City*.

The only scene I remember involves characters in a room, with wooden planks on the floor and the walls. The center is bare and prisoners face a group questioning them.

They are wearing what looks like pirate or sailor costumes from an earlier century.

At the center of the room is a trap door. After questioning one of the prisoners, one of the men opens the trap door, revealing the mouth of a monster. The prisoner is thrown into the trap door and is eaten by the monster, feet first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only other film that this remotely reminds me of is [The Lost Continent](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063240/) from 1968.

> This film starts out like the Love Boat on acid, as a cast of varied characters, with various issues, take Captain Eric Portman's leaky cargo ship to escape their troubles. When a violent storm strikes, the ship is swept into the Sargasso Sea and our heroes find themselves trapped on an island of man-eating seaweed, populated by giant monster crabs and some Spanish conquistadors who think the Inquisition is still on.

Comment: Yes, that must be it! The trap door with the mouth of the monster is shown in the trailer. Thanks very much!